# Magento2 Configurable product options not showing after data migration

Tags: magento2, configurable-product, magento2-migration-tool

After migration from Magento 1.9.3.6 to 2.3.5-p1 (also tested on 2.3.3, 2.3.4) the associated products for configured items are not available.

First off, color is not added to attribute set "Default" or any others. It was correctly added in Magento 1.
After adding the attribute to the attribute sets, I face the following problems.

When editing the configurable product:

- color and size are required to be selected as if they are not being used for configurable options.
- all associated simple products are missing from the list

I checked the database to verify the tables catalog_product_super_attribute and catalog_product_super_link, all the links seem to be there and look correct.

It seems as though the configurable product does not know which attributes are being used for configurations, but all the data is correctly there in catalog_product_super_attribute and catalog_product_super_link.

Has anyone else experienced this problem? Does anyone know a fix for this?

Comment: Have you find solution?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out simple products were missing their color attribute values.
Because of this, configurable product super attributes (color / size) were not disabled when editing configurable product and associated products were not set.

After manual repair of simple product attributes, it worked properly.

For some reason, the data migration lost all attribute values for color. A manual export from source database and repair on new database solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue. What fixed it for me was to add the color attribute to the default attribute set **before** running the data migration. Instead of fixing it afterwards in the database I just ran the entire migration again.